# Java: Finding duplicate in array

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

**I need to implement a duplicate search method in my program, but getting errors. 
If I comment out the duplicate search part, the program runs fine.**

**Error (I commented out the duplicate search part**):

```
  do{ 
   System.out.print("Please enter an integer or -1 to stop: ");
   input=Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine()); //parse library function 
   /** 
    * for(int i=0; i<A.length; i++){
    *     for(int j=i+1; j<A.length; j++{
    *         if(A[i].equals(A[j]))
    *         System.out.println("Duplicate input. Please enter another 
                          value: ");
    *         }
    *       }
    */
   if(input != -1) //if input is 
   Display.userInput(input);
}
while(input != -1);
```

Comment: and what's the problem?

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<A.length; i++){
        if(A[i].equals(input))
              System.out.println("Duplicate input. Please enter another 
                         value: ");
}` why 2 loop just check current input is in array or not

Comment: cause i need to first check for duplicate and then check if input is -1 or not.

Comment: [I downvoted because your problem statement is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).

Comment: just to suggest can you use array list instead of array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
do{ 
   System.out.print("Please enter an integer or -1 to stop: ");
   input=Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
   boolean flag = true;
   for(int i=0; i<A.length; i++){ 
      if(A[i].equals(input)) {
          System.out.println("Duplicate input. Please enter another value: ");
          flag = false;
          break;
      }
   }
   if(!flag) {
      continue;
   }
   if(input != -1) //if input is 
   Display.userInput(input);
}

while(input != -1);
```

Comment: thanks so much. I am new to stack..so I don't know the convention of posting questions. Thanks for fully understanding my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int A[] = {1, 5, 9, 5, 6};
    if (Arrays.stream(A).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity()))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .map(Collection::size)
            .anyMatch(s -> s > 1)) {
        System.out.println("Duplicate input. Please enter another value:");
    }
```